# Enable featured image in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am converting an HTML site to WordPress. In my new theme I have no option for a featured image. How can I enable this option?

Comment: Have you checked the checkbox in screen options in edit post/page ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

in your function.php

Comment: I tried this code but it is not working. Any other basic functions is needed in functions.php?

Comment: No there isn't this should works straight forward. If you just checked twentyfourteen template, you will find these lines:-

`// Enable support for Post Thumbnails, and declare two sizes.
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 672, 372, true );
add_image_size( 'twentyfourteen-full-width', 1038, 576, true );`

If you just removed them away, feature image module will not work.